# Trying to update html dynamically in typescript

Tags: html, typescript, ionic5

I have an html file that lists the latitudinal position of a user. I can currently update the html text when I click a button, which calls a typescript function. What I want is for my function to be called onload, updating the text before the page is even fully loaded. I have tried using the onload function, but have had no luck. Here is my html, assuming I cleaned up my code correctly it should be reproducible:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
    <div id="container">
      <h1>Go-To-Gate Reminder</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <ion-icon size="large" name="walk"></ion-icon>
        <p> Walking speed </p>
        <text id="updater"></text>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-app>
```

and here is my ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
    framework = 'At exact boarding time';

    constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {}

// use geolocation to get user's device coordinates
getCurrentCoordinates() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
        this.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
        this.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });

    document.getElementById("updater").innerHTML = '&nbsp' + this.latitude
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the `getCurrentCoordinates` method from within the constructor.